# Изменить высоту border

Tags: css

Как я могу регулировать высоту, например правого `border`, если меня не устраивает его автоматическое покрытие всего контента в блоке? `border-image`? тогда подскажите как мне сделать `border-image` только для определенной стороны, заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот пример с border-image для одной (нижней) стороны

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 10px; }

div {
background-color: #e2e2e2;
border: solid transparent;
border-width: 0 0 20px;
border-image:url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/love-line-colorful-drawing-vertical-seamless-pattern-illustration-lines-background-graphic-texture-wallpaper-64879256.jpg") 2 repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для задания `border` только одной из сторон используются свойства:

- `border-top` верхний
- `border-bottom` нижний
- `border-left` левый
- `border-right` правый

Толщину `border` можно задавать через `border-width` или прямо в `border` вторым значением.

```css
div {
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-right: solid 15px blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>div 100x100</div>
```

Comment: У вас `border-image` со знаком вопроса т.е. вы не уверены, из дальнейшего описания вопроса я подумал, что вам нужно изменить стили определенного бордера.